# Survival probability given an average life expectancy

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How can I obtain the probability that one person will die at or before a certain age if I only have the average of the life expectancy?

For instance, a person is 45 years old. The life expectancy is 60 years. Can I find the probability the person will die at age 45 (not before 44, but not after 45)?

Comment: It can't be done. Case 1: everyone dies at 60 -> 0% probability. Case 2, 50% die at 45, 50% die at 75 -> 50% probability. You need a survival curve.

Comment: This is equivalent to trying to recover a probability distribution from its mean.  It's impossible without making some very strong assumption about the distribution, e.g. that it's exponential (which wouldn't be realistic at all).

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the comments above and after some searching, I found these datasets ([WHO Life tables by country](http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.60000?lang=en) ) which helped me with the prediction that I want. In fact, apparently is imposible to determine the probability of survival with just the life expectancy, these datasets provide the survival probability for age based on the gender and the country.